# Crystal Load capacitors & ESR

Tags: voltage, capacitor, oscillator, crystal, load

In the [KSZ8863 datasheet,](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002335B.pdf) the crystal specification is given (table 9-3), page 85.

Here the ESR is specified to 40ohms with no minimum nor maximum marking.
Load capacitance is specified to a max of 20pF.

My Selected quartz has an 18pF load and 40ohms - which should fit the specification.

Calculation in this [App Note](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00849a.pdf) shows that 2 capacitors of 22pF are fine for an equivalent 18pF load.

One drawback is the power dissipated (measured) in the crystal is ~150uW (nominal for that type is 100uW).

The next drawback is the gain margin for starting oscillation. By adding an additional resistor next to the crystal, the gain or negative resistance margin is calculated to be ~2, where commonly available sources refer to ~5.

Empirical try-and-fail shows that the current of the crystal can be easily reduced by changing primarily selected capacitors (2x22pF) to e.g. 2x10pF. BY changing that capacitor there is an improvement in gain margin too.

Appropriate crystal for 2x10pF load has ESR on the level of 60...100ohms.

The question is if the generator circuitry inside the Switch device will stable operate with a higher ESR of crystal.
Any idea on the max value (similar to the 20pF max of CL)?

Comment: There's no mention of the oscillator's *frequency*...how important is it to you to oscillate at the printed frequency? Choosing smaller \$C_L\$ raises frequency above the spec value.

Comment: @glen_geek , thank you for the comment. The oscillator's frequency is 25MHz.

Comment: Bigger loading capacitance means more power dissipation.

Comment: @Andyaka, thank you for the comment. If a selected crystal specifies a CL value of 18pF, then ideally (with Cstray and other parasitics), the individual load capacitor value of 36pF (twice the CL) should be right, right?

Comment: Didn't we discuss this in a recent previous question but, yes, if we ignore the parasitics then 36 pF will be required on each side of the crystal.

Comment: @Andyaka, yes. We did discuss. Just wanted to say this here because, in the app note attached in the question, equation on page 4, gives a load capacitor (each) value of of very less than twice the CL of the crystal, right?

Comment: That assumes a very high stray capacitance of 12.5 pF; what will your design have?

Comment: @Andyaka, probably less than 2-3pF.

Comment: @Andyaka, Any idea on my initial question on " if the generator circuitry inside the Switch device will stable operate with a higher ESR of crystal. Any idea on the max value (similar to the 20pF max of CL)?"

Comment: I have no answer to that unfortunately.

Comment: @Andyaka, ok. But in general, what is the limit of the crystal ESR with respect to the crystal oscillation?

Comment: There is no general limit. The chip is designed with some parameters that are unknown to us, and you only get the typical and/or maximum parameters for the crystal. You don't get enough info about tge chip to calculate what is the maximum tolerable ESR from the crystal, and it anyway depends on the capacitors. If you have calculated that it is difficult to use the crystal that you have chosen, then the calculations prove that the crystal is a poor choise.